# Maven goal to generate test report using damage control

Tags: maven, spock, test-reporting

I'm using Spock to test a Java application. I would like to generate test reports, in html, using [damage-control](https://github.com/damage-control/report)

What maven goal shoud be executed to generate the reports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It generated the reports running:

```
    mvn com.github.damage-control.report:damage-control-maven-plugin:report
```

Comment: This plugin is no more maintenance. And it doesn't work on Java 8. Is there any plugin similar like this ?

Comment: @royki there are options like Clover, Jacoco or Cobertura, not sure how they work today, support may have been dropped as language evolved.

https://openclover.org
https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura/issues/184
https://github.com/codecov/example-groovy

Answer (score 1):

You should use **goal** provided by plugin.
Maven provides only **phase**'s, not goals
So you should use phase `test` and goal `report`.

```
  <execution>
    <phase>test</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>report</goal>
    </goals>
  </execution>
```

`report` goal is declared in this file [DamageControlMojo](https://github.com/damage-control/report/blob/master/plugins/maven/src/main/java/com/github/damagecontrol/report/plugins/maven/DamageControlMojo.java).

```
/**
 * @goal report
 */
```

Comment: I use an alternative way to call the plugin's goal. Thanks to point that I should use the plugin's goal and not a maven goal.